# white labeling and Django application

Tags: django

I've just been approached by my boss about the possibility of white labeling our Django-based site for a new, large customer.  Basically, it sounds like it would mainly be changing the graphics/logos on the site. But, I'm sure that at some point they will want to start tweaking the business logic as well. I'm still unclear whether the desire is for it to be a subdomain (e.g. customer.mydomain.com) or a completely new custom domain.  Ultimately, it *will* need to share the database with the rest of the system (for multiple reasons).  Is this a good use of the Sites Framework in Django?  Or is there a better way of doing this?

More info:  Django 1.3.1; PostgreSQL 9.1; Hosted on Heroku

Comment: Django sites framework should be just fine, but it's hard to give you precise answer without having a more detailed overview.

Answer (score 0):

Use a combination of middleware (to set the active site) and context processors (to act on that).  You could try to hook into contrib's site framework, but I've always outgrown it rather quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It sounds like you have done this sort of thing before.  Is that true?  Any additional information you can post to your answer will be very appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: @DavidS: Yes, I have done this before.  How to accomplish it really depends on a number of other factors.  Feel free to email me @ samdolan at gmail dot com